# Looking for walkway advice

Tags: walkway

I am seeking suggestions for walkway repair. I have a walkway (as seen in the photo) with 2x4s that are rotting in the exposed area and need to be replaced. The dimensions of this area are exactly 75" x 75". The existing lumber is 20 of 2x4 and 1 of 2x2 (all 75" long). I could just replace with new 2x4s and a 2x2. However, I want to able to "open" this space to get underneath the walkway here. Which means creating either a 75"x75" plate that I can remove or two smaller 37.5" x 75" plates. Any suggestions on how I might go about constructing this? In order to meet up with the rest of the walkway, the thickness needs to be the same as the existing 2x4s (approx 1.5"). Also, I prefer materials that don't need to be painted and can withstand Oregon rain. Currently I am thinking composite 2x4s that are connected by two 2x4s running perpendicular underneath the top beams and between the walkway support beams. But I am looking for other ideas.
[image: walkway photo]

Comment: Composite materials would certainly be useful for withstanding rain and ground contact - make sure the ones you're selecting are designed for ground contact. As I understand you, you're essentially looking to make 2 "doors" (though they might not be hinged) so you can get access to the ground beneath? Is there a hole below or would they be directly supported by the ground? That will help determine the framing requirements.

Comment: There is a crawlspace below the boards. They are supported by three perpendicular beams. Yes, ideally I would create two removeable panels - each with 10 2x4s, plus a 2x2 nailed in place at the top or bottom. I wish the walkway was a tad narrower - being just over 6 feet wide makes for bad math when trying to buy lumber. Though I could nail a 2x2 into each side to make up for that extra three inches beyond 6 feet. That would also hold the boards together without having to run perpendicular boards underneath, between the beams. However, those 2x2s on the sides would not be supported underneath.